# django-mptt different data ordering on two machines with same code and data

Tags: django, postgresql, django-mptt

I'm using django-mptt library for creating directory hierarchy like this:

```
directory_a
   directory_some_name
       directory_a
       directory_b
   directory_some_name
directory_b
   directory_some_name
   directory_some_name
```

models.py

```py
class BaseDirectory(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=120)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,
                            blank=True, related_name='children',
                            verbose_name=_('parent directory'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def clean(self):
        # some cleaning
        super().clean()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.clean()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class OtherDirectory(BaseDirectory):
    # directory model from another application
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('directory')
        verbose_name_plural = _('directories')
```

I deployed this code to server and it works fine(all items inserting in *alphabetic order*, if i change it somehow and run `OtherDirectory.objects.rebuild()` it returns back to normal alphabetic order.
But locally on my machine *alphabetic ordering* didn't work. It's randomly puts new element into parent tree.

I'am tried to download database backup from my server and restore it locally, but if i run `OtherDirectory.objects.rebuild()` data again shuffled in wrong order.

After some researching of django-mptt sources and debugging my app i found out this queryset in [django mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/blob/master/mptt/models.py#L221) contains different data between my local machine and server with same db data and code, `filters` and `order_by`:

```py
queryset = node.__class__._tree_manager.db_manager(
                node._state.db).filter(filters).order_by(*order_by)
```

And now i'm stuck. Why this can be?

local machine: OS X Mojave. DB: postgresql 9.6.10 with postgis 2.5.2, python3.7.3, django 2.1.7, django-mptt 0.9.1

server: Ubuntu, postgresql 9.6.10 with postgis 2.5.1 python3.7.1, django 2.1.7,  django-mptt 0.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out solution. The problem was in postgresql ordering by Russian words on OS X. Fix with following steps in this [article](http://evtuhovich.ru/blog/2012/07/14/collate-osx-postgres/)(in Russian) .